# To use or not to use computed columns for performance and maintainability

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

I have a table where am storing a startingDate in a DateTime column.

Once i have the **startingDate** value, am supposed to calculate the

- number_of_days,
- number_of_weeks
- number_of_months and
- number_of_years

all from the startingDate to the current date.

If you are going to use these values in two or more places in the application and you do care much about the applications response time, would you rather make the calculations in a view or create computed columns for each so you can query the table directly?

Comment: Profile and find out if that is the bottleneck in your application. If not, don't worry and improve real bottlenecks first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed columns are easy to maintain and provide an ideal solution to your problem – I have used such a solution recently. However, be aware the values are calculated when requested (when they are SELECTed), not when the row is INSERTed into the table – so performance might still be an issue. This might be acceptable if you can off-load work from the application server to the database server. Views also don’t exist until they are requested (unless they are materialised) so, again, there will be an overhead at runtime, but, again it’s on the database server, not the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Like nearly everything: It depends.

As @RedX suggest it probably not much of a performance difference either way, so it becomes a question of how will use them. To me this is more of a feel thing.

Using them more than once doesn't wouldn't necessary drive me immediately to either a view or computed columns. If I only use them in a few places or low volume code paths I might calc them in-line in those places or use a CTE. But if the are in wide spread or heavy use I would agree with a view or computed column.

You would also want them in a view or cc if you want them available via ORM tools.

Am I using those "computed columns" individual in places or am I using them in sets? If using them in sets I probably want a view of the table that shows included them all.

When i need them do I usually want them associated with data from a particular other table? If so that would suggest a view.

Am I basing updates on the original table of those computed values? If so then I want computed columns to avoid joining the view in these case.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns may seem an easy solution at first, but I have seen companies have trouble with them because when they try to do ETL with CDC for real-time Change Data Capture with tools like Attunity it will not recognize the calculated columns since the values are not there permanently. So there are some issues. Also if the columns will be retrieve many, many times by users, you will save time in the long run by putting that logic in the ETL tool or procedure and write it once to the database instead of calculating it many times for each request.